# Set pandas dataframe winner column value based on majority value from three other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas df as this

```
id  Vote1     Vote2      Vote3 
123 Positive  Negative   Positive
223 Positive  Negative   Neutral 
323 Positive  Negative   Negative  
423 Positive  Positive
```

I want to add another column with name `winner`
which will be set to whatever is the majority of votes and **if there is a tie then the first vote will be set, as shown for id= 223**

So the result df should be

```
id  Vote1     Vote2      Vote3      Winner
123 Positive  Negative   Positive   Positive
223 Positive  Negative   Neutral    Positive
323 Positive  Negative   Negative   Negative 
423 Positive  Positive              Positive
```

This might be related to 
[Update Pandas Cells based on Column Values and Other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987860/update-pandas-cells-based-on-column-values-and-other-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this row-by-row, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id']=[123,223,323,423]
df['Vote1']=['Positive']*4
df['Vote2']=['Negative']*3+['Positive']
df['Vote3']=['Positive','Neutral','Negative','']

mostCommonVote=[]
for row in df[['Vote1','Vote2','Vote3']].values:
    votes, values = np.unique(row, return_counts=True)
    if np.all(values<=1):
            mostCommonVote.append( row[0] )
    else:
        mostCommonVote.append( votes[np.argmax(values)] )

df['Winner'] = mostCommonVote
```

Result:

```
 df:
    id     Vote1     Vote2     Vote3    Winner
0  123  Positive  Negative  Positive  Positive
1  223  Positive  Negative   Neutral  Positive
2  323  Positive  Negative  Negative  Negative
3  423  Positive  Positive            Positive
```

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it is quite simple. It uses the numpy function **unique** which can return the counts for each unique string for the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Another, Pandas solution without looping:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
rep = {'Positive':1,'Negative':-1,'Neutral':0}
df1 = df.replace(rep)

df = df.assign(Winner=np.where(df1.sum(axis=1) > 0,'Positive',np.where(df1.sum(axis=1) < 0, 'Negative', df.iloc[:,0])))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Vote1     Vote2     Vote3    Winner
id                                         
123  Positive  Negative  Positive  Positive
223  Positive  Negative   Neutral  Positive
323  Positive  Negative  Negative  Negative
423  Positive  Positive       NaN  Positive
```

## Explanation

`df.assign` is a way to create column in a copy of the original dataframe, therefore you have to re assign back to df.  The name of the column is `Winner`, hence 'winner='.

Next, you have nested if statements using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) ... np.where(cond,result,else)

```
np.where(df.sum(axis=1) > 0,  # this sums the dataframe by row
         'Positive',  #if true
         np.where(df.sum(axis=1) < 0, #nested if the first if return false  
                  'Negative', #sum of the row is less than 0
                  df.iloc[:,0] #sum = 0 get the first value from that row.
                  )
         )
```

Comment: This looks better, do you mind explaining a bit about ```Winner=np.where(df1.sum(axis=1) > 0,'Positive',np.where(df1.sum(axis=1) < 0, 'Negative', df.iloc[:,0]))```

Comment: Sure, those are basically if statements.  np.where(cond,result,else)

Comment: So, i have a nested if statement with the np.wheres

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function and apply it to the df. It is usually a bit faster than normal looping.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def vote(row):
    pos = np.sum(row.values == 'Positive')
    neg = np.sum(row.values == 'Negative')
    if pos > neg:
        return('Positive')
    elif pos < neg: 
        return('Negative')
    else:
        return(row['Vote1'])

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id']=[123,223,323,423]
df['Vote1']=['Positive']*4
df['Vote2']=['Negative']*3+['Positive']
df['Vote3']=['Positive','Neutral','Negative','']
df = df.set_index('id')
df['Winner'] = df.apply(vote,axis=1)
```

Result

```
Out[41]: 
        Vote1     Vote2     Vote3    Winner
id                                         
123  Positive  Negative  Positive  Positive
223  Positive  Negative   Neutral  Positive
323  Positive  Negative  Negative  Negative
423  Positive  Positive            Positive
```